# Designing a sell point database

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design

I am building a database for a small shop where the client can enter different kinds of payments. Now all the payments share common columns (eg. amount, debit or credit, date of payment, etc ...), so I decided to make a table of payments.

The problem is some payments may be associated with other entities (tables) (eg. a certain payment associated with a dealer with whom the client is dealing), and some are not associated with any table.

As I see it, it's like the payments share all attributes except that certain payments might have foreign keys to other tables.

Question: best way to model this situation ?

Comment: nothing wrong with having nullable FK's..

Comment: Is your question really about how to model the situation?  Or is it about how to design tables to implement the model?

Comment: @WalterMitty probably both !

Comment: @Blorgbeard Nothing wrong, but it just seems bad design to add a nullable FK for each table the payments may be associated with.